# add output in command

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I started only a few weeks ago with scripting or I am trying at least ...

```
bash-4.3# /usr/openv/netbackup/bin/admincmd/bperror -backstat -hoursago 72 \
          | grep xxx1                                                      \
          | awk '{ print $1 "\t" $19 "\t" $12 "\t" $14 "\t" $16 }'  >> test
bash-4.3# cat test
1535229470      0       xxx1     policy1        sched1
1535314239      0       xxx1     policy1        sched1
1535400749      0       xxx1     policy1        sched1
```

Now I want to transform the first entry (timestamp) into a readable date

```
date=$(awk 'NR == 1 {print $1}' test); bpdbm -ctime $date |awk '{ print $3 " " $4 " " $5 " " $6 " " $8 }'
Sat Aug 25 22:37:50 2018
```

How can I now replace the first entry on each line by this output or change the first command?

thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk:

```
awk '$1~/[0-9]+/{$1=strftime(PROCINFO["strftime"],$1)}1' file
```

This replaces the timestamp in the first field of the line with the associated readable date using the function `strftime`.

The date format is the default one `PROCINFO["strftime"]` as mentioned in the awk man page.

Comment: bash-4.3# awk '$1~/[0-9]+/{$1=strftime(PROCINFO["strftime"],$1)}1' test.txt
 
awk: 0602-553 Function strftime is not defined.

 The input line number is 1. The file is test.txt.

 The source line number is 1.

bash-4.3#

Comment: @Juan Please make sure you use *GNU* awk version (see `awk --version`)

Comment: Its a AIX host!

Comment: @Juan This is an information that should definitively be part of your question since it greatly impacts the answer one can give.

Comment: @Juan So this GNU awk script won't work on your system... I think you have to look towards a perl solution. Good luck.